# While running I can't get app to recognize bankcustomers once added, customers are stored in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
MAIN CLASS -
```

Here's where I generate the arrayList and open the menu to begin adding customers. After I run option 1 (customer added) is where my app gets stuck. I then run option 2 to make a deposit, and it doesn't recall the info I put in for option 1.

```
package BankCustomer;
```

``

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{


    //create an arraylist for the bankcustomers
    ArrayList<BankCustomer> list = new ArrayList<BankCustomer>();





    //bring in necessary variables for computation
    BankCustomer b;

    String name, address;
    int accountNumber;
    double balance, dep;
    String resp;
    boolean done = false;

    //set up the menu
      while(!done){
          resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose a command from\n" +
                         "\t1: Add a new customer\n" +
                         "\t2: Make a deposit\n" +
                         "\t3: Make a withdrawal\n" +
                         "\t4: Look up a balance\n" +
                         "\t5: Remove a customer\n" +
                         "\t6: Total bank balance\n" +
                         "\t7: Quit" );
          int cmd = Integer.parseInt(resp);
          switch(cmd) {


    case 1:
                      //add a customer
                      name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the customer");
                      address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer address");
                      resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the accountNumber");
                      accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(resp);
                      resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the balance");
                      balance = Double.parseDouble(resp);
                      b = new BankCustomer(address, name, accountNumber, balance);
                      list.add(b);
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      //make customer deposits

                      name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the customer to deposit for");

                      resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount to deposit");
                      dep = Double.parseDouble(resp);

                    Iterator<BankCustomer> iter = list.iterator();




                    boolean found = false;
                    while(!found && iter.hasNext()){

                        b = iter.next();
                        if(b.getName().compareTo(name) == 0){

                            b.deposit(dep);
                            found = true;
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer deposit complete");



                        }
                    }
                    if(!found){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such bank customer");
                    }

                      break;
                  case 3:

                      //make customer withdrawals
                      name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the customer to withdraw from");
                      resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount to withdraw");
                       double with = Double.parseDouble(resp);

                    found = false;
                    iter = list.iterator();

                    while(!found && iter.hasNext()){
                        b = iter.next();
                        if(b.getName().compareTo(name) == 0){

                            b.withdrawal(with);
                            found = true;
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer withdrawal complete");

                        }
                    }
                    if(!found){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such bank customer");
                    }




                      break;
                  case 4:
                      //look up customers by name
                   name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the customer to show the balance");


                    found = false;
                    iter = list.iterator();

                    while(!found && iter.hasNext()){
                        b = iter.next();
                        if(b.getName().compareTo(name) == 0){

                            b.getBalance();
                            found = true;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b.getBalance());
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such bank customer");
                    }

                      break;

                  case 5:
                      //remove customers by name
                     name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the customer to remove");


                    found = false;
                    iter = list.iterator();

                    while(!found && iter.hasNext()){
                        b = iter.next();
                        if(b.getName().compareTo(name) == 0){

                            iter.remove();
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such bank customer");
                    } 

                      break;
                  case 6:
                      //total balances of all customers in the bank
                      double total = 0.0;

                    iter = list.iterator();

                    while(iter.hasNext()){
                        b = iter.next();
                        total = total + b.getBalance();
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total balance of bank" + total);

                      break;
                  case 7:
                      //close the menu
                      done = true;
              }

          }


    }

}




BANKCUSTOMER CLASS

package BankCustomer;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
//introduce attributes and serialize the information
public class BankCustomer implements Serializable, Comparable<BankCustomer>{

private String name, address;
private int accountNumber;
private double balance;



 //constructor with passable values
    public BankCustomer(String name, String address, int accountNumber, double balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

//option for no argument constructor
public BankCustomer() {
    this.name = "Tyler Ridings";
    this.address = "unknown";
    this.accountNumber = 0;
    this.balance = 0.0;
}

//setters and getters
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}


public int getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


//method for making a deposit
public void deposit(double bal) {
    this.balance = this.balance + bal;
}

//method for making a withdrawal
public boolean withdrawal(double bal) {
    if(this.balance > bal){
        this.balance = this.balance -bal;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    }

//compareTo for iterator jobs
public int compareTo(BankCustomer x){
    return accountNumber - x.getAccountNumber();
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, indent your code and remove all the redundant blank lines. This code is illegible.

Comment: Why are you using an iterator? Why can't you use indexOf()

Comment: Can't you narrow the source of your problem to anything less than your whole code? You'd get much better answers if you could describe your problem more precisely. Also: please fix your code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up the order of parameters in the call to BankCustomer constructor. You're calling it as:

```
b = new BankCustomer(address, name, accountNumber, balance);
```

Whereas the declaration is:

```
public BankCustomer(String name, String address, int accountNumber, double balance) { ... }
```

Comment: Sorry man its my first post so im still learning how to format everything. Thank you for the response though, ill give this a shot. The only reason i posted the entirety of the code is because i figured it was only 2 classes and you guys would need to see stuff from bankcustomer to know what might need to change in main.